# Using AppSync via CloudFront with the CDK

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-appsync, aws-cdk

I want to deploy a AppSync API behind a CloudFront distribution.

The CloudFront distribution needs an HTTP origin, how do I get this from my API object inside one CDK stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. Had to use an intrinsic function to get the right value out of the distribution construct.

```js
const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(...);

const origin = new origins.HttpOrigin(
  cdk.Fn.select(2, cdk.Fn.split("/", api.graphqlUrl))
);

const distribution = new cloudfront.Distribution(this, "DemoDistribution", {
  defaultBehavior: { origin },
});
```